# Outdoor Spigot Replacement can't unscrew stem, just spins

Tags: plumbing, spigot

Trying to replace an outdoor spigot, that connects underneath kitchen sink. I have a pipe wrench on what I think is the attaching pipe, but the spigot just spins and spins and doesn't come loose? Wondering if it's soldered on, but then it shouldn't turn at all?

The Stem for the Spigot is in the wall, and connected to something (Gold/Brass) connector that looks connected to the copper threaded pipe?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure that it is threaded.  Maybe its press fit.  Is the outside smooth and round or does it look like a nut ?

Comment: Think those bronze/brass colour rings are crimp rings for pex pipe.  Depending on type might need to be cut off.

Comment: ok, thats what I was worried about. It's such a tight space with all the other kitchen sink pipes. It's going to be hard to get in and replace.

Comment: If the rings are removed, the idea is that fitting should pop off.  In real life in tight places, quite a bit of force/pulling(plus language not for children) is required.

Comment: Thanks, will look into cutting crimp rings.

Comment: Could you give another try at the picture and [edit] it in? There are lots of pixels but not much detail  (focus or lighting is off, I think) when I zoom in, and I can't *really* see what's going on where it matters.

Comment: This appears to be a picture of the _inside_. Usually the spigot would be removed from the _outside_. How about a picture there - there's a good chance that you'll be able to get to it from outside.

Comment: @FreeMan a proper sill-cock for freezing areas extends all the way through the wall so that the valve is inside the house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I can tell from "the sill-cocks I've met" and your picture, the sill-cock is a typical "threaded outside, solder inside" which has had a PEX fitting soldered in, inside and then crimped. It's not very clear but I *think* I see the outside male threads on the end of the sill-cock.

This is actually somewhat fortunate for you. When people try to unscrew these on a soldered copper pipe system, they twist the pipe they are attached to, and have more damage to repair. Since PEX fittings act like unions (the fitting turns inside the pipe and ring) you're just spinning, rather than damaging your other pipes.

I would suggest replacing with a PEX-FIP (female iron pipe threads) fitting so you can unscrew the next one. Here, you'll need to cut the copper crimp ring so you can remove the soldered in fitting and the attached sill-cock.

**However:** It's possible (picture is *not* great) that **you may already have this**, and just need to grab on the outside of the FIP fitting, if you have one. That would be a bit further into the hole than you are now, if you have a bronze/brass fitting that male threads from the sill-cock are going into. If I ignore the picture and read the text, that sounds like the case, so you need to grab that, not the crimp ring on the PEX connected to it.

Comment: So the "sill-cock" had a PEX fitting soldered on, and I was able to replace by cutting the PEX pipe and Clamps and replacing the PEX and Clamp rings. Was a pain to do because it was underneath the sink. The original faucet had a unique thread on there that was designed to only fit one kinda of vacuum breaker which was why I was replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

To me that looks like quick connect/disconnect type.

It is not screwed, it is a insert.

Push/Pull the black ring and it will pop out'

Answer (score 0):

That hose bib looks to be connected via pex.  Turn off the water, cut the pex, pull the hose bib and get a frost-free version for replacement.  You'll need pex rings, a 90 and a 1/2" crimp tool.  You can get a crimp ring removal tool but unless you are doing a lot of plumbing it likely isn't worth it.

A different option to consider is a yard hydrant.  Instead of the hose bib that breaks and leaks into your house, you install a frost free yard hydrant off your water service and have it located where most convenient for a hose.

They are a bit pricer maybe $120 for the hydrant but they aren't trip hazards and you get to choose the most convenient location and since they are frost free they never pose any danger of causing water damage inside your house.  You also avoid penetrations in your WRB / AB and VB.

[image]

[yard hydrant](https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/Water-Source-YH-4-4-ft-Yard-Hydrant/PRD5YLF8W15OW85?skuId=5YLF8W15OW85&offerId=F061F707F94B4025A9D73CB15F009C59&utm_medium=paid_search&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=always_on&cmpid=SEM_CA_316_K0VOW691KF_71700000099943864_58700008013744804&utm_id=SEM_CA_316_K0VOW691KF_71700000099943864_58700008013744804&gclid=Cj0KCQiAorKfBhC0ARIsAHDzsls5Ps5CCbSxsdu6CCr8U022WvVLOZlPZX7xK4d8jol0nUR2e2A52SUaAqxyEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: This does not address removing the present sill-cock, (which is the question) which may well have failed in some manner other than freezing anyway.